# CSS top-and-bottom padding: split evenly within fixed-height border

Tags: css, padding

I've been asked to put a certificate online, that users can then print out.  Everything's good to go except I'm having trouble centering everything vertically.

I have on div that holds the border (#outerBorder) and another one nested inside of that which holds all the stuff (#wrapper).  The #outerBorder has a fixed height, such that the certificate will have a nice even margin when printed.  I'd like the #wrapper to be vertically centered inside it, so that there is even padding between the top and bottom of the #outerBorder and #wrapper.

Is there a way to do this without manually calculating and then hard-coding the numbers?  The closest solution I've found is this one: [Evenly distribute images vertically within fixed-height space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12266788/evenly-distribute-images-vertically-within-fixed-height-space)
But I'd really prefer to not use a table.

I've also tried putting "vertical-align: middle;" in the CSS for #wrapper, but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Thanks!
-Kristin

Comment: The answer in the question you linked to is *not* using a table.

Comment: So the "display:table" is used for non-table div's?

Comment: Absolutely. `display: table` just tells the element to act like a table in terms of how it displays on the page.  You need an element to have the display property of `table-cell` to get vertical align working like you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Middle align in CSS is unnecessarily elusive.

One option is adding this to your wrapper:

```
vertical-align:middle;    
display:table-cell;
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S7JGr/) example

Comment: Thanks!!  That did exactly what I wanted.  I guess I need to look into this "display:table" and "display:table-cell" more closely - I thought they could only be used with tables. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
Many CSS property not supported by the print media..

At first I can say you use media print tag and write css inside of that for print.Like - 
@media print {
   your css
}
or use external file like 
<LINK rel="stylesheet" type"text/css" href="print.css" media="print">

Now please write vertical-align: middle; inside of the print media.

Another idea may be work but it's depend of the structure of the page.That's you can use % value.Like

#outerBorder{
   height :100%;
}

#wrapper{
  height:80%;
  min-height:80%;
  margin-top:10%;
}
```