# Center text in fixed height div

Tags: css, positioning

I want to center some text in a fixed height div.

I've made the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wzNp3/)

```
<div style="height:180px;border:1px solid black;vertical-align:middle;">
     <h1 style="vertical-align:middle;">Contact</h1> 
</div>

<div style="height:180px;border:1px solid black;vertical-align:middle;">
    <h2>Welcome to the</h2>
    <h1>AAA</h1>
    <h4>system</h4>
</div>
```

I've tried various options of the vertical-align:middle applying it to the different elements but it doesn't seem to work.

I did see other questions where the line-height was set to the same height as the font-size but in the second example I have multiple lines of text at different heights.

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16244387/css-top-and-bottom-padding-split-evenly-within-fixed-height-border/16244775#16244775

Comment: Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/wzNp3/1/)?

Comment: The line-height equal to height technique is great if you are vertically centering inline elements on a single line.  However, you are dealing with a different layout situation where you want to vertically center a block with a variable number of lines.  In this case, the table-cell approach is probably the best.  However, note that table-cell is not supported in IE7.

Answer (score 7):

Used to `display` `table-cell`

**as like this**

```
.parent{
    height:180px;border:1px solid black;vertical-align:middle;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/wzNp3/2/)

**Don't** use to `inline css` write a class in `external css` and `define css`

Comment: the div also has a float left applied to it http://jsfiddle.net/wzNp3/8/ which seems to be messing it up, any ideas?

Comment: Than use to line-height if single line in this box as like this http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/wzNp3/11/

Comment: Unfortunately I can't apply line height as this is in a template and I dont know at run time if the text is going to be single or multi line

Answer (score 0):

Vertical alignment always comes with some trouble. You should apply that css property only to table (td) elements and inline elements, not block elements like divs.

To position something in the middle you can use very simple solution - by using absolute positioning.

Create child block and set it's position to absolute, move it 50% from top, and set margin-top to negative value with amout equal to half of parent's height. Set your parents position to relative.

```
#parent {
    position: relative;
    height: 180px;
}

#child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -90px;
}

<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
        <h1>sample</h1>
        <h2>sample</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```