# Equally distribute empty space vertically (above, below, and in between elements) in css

Tags: css

I found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12266788/evenly-distribute-images-vertically-within-fixed-height-space) about vertically distributing three images over a space with fixed height.

I want to distribute three buttons over a space with fixed height but I need the empty (red) space to be equally distributed **between elements and on top and above the first and last element** respectively. This is my code:

```
<-- HTML -->
<ul id="button-list">
<li><span><button>1st button</button></span></li>
<li><span><button>2nd button</button></span></li>
<li><span><button>3rd button</button></span></li>
</ul>

<-- CSS -->
#button-list { display:table; height:150px; background: red}
#button-list button { width: 100%; display:block }
#button-list li { display:table-row }
#button-list li span { display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; background:red }
#button-list li:first-child,
#button-list li:last-child { height:20px }
```

Here is the [changed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Federicopvs/mx9x3z2o/). Any idea?

p.s: I have tried the code without the `<span>` tags because I thought that the `<button>` tags could substitute them. It didn't work, why?

Answer (score 0):

If you simple erase `#img-list li:first-child, #img-list li:last-child { height:20px }` and `#img-list li:first-child,#img-list li:last-child { height:20px }`, you can get the desired result with the code (table stuff) you are already using:

http://jsfiddle.net/jhLhhf1u/2/